# Select all rows in active page only jquery Datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using jquery datatable on a gidview and there is a checkbox on the datatable header. The purpose of that checkbox is to check all checkboxes in the current page of the gridview rows.

So am using the function

```
var table = $('#Tab_ApplicantList').DataTable();
    var rows = $('#Tab_ApplicantList').dataTable().fnGetNodes();
    $(rows).each(function () {
        $(this).find("input.grey").iCheck('check');
    });
```

But the problem is it is selecting all rows in the datatable, not just the rows in the active page. So how can I achieve that to check rows in the current page alone?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've got an answer to my question and sharing for those with similar issue..

```
var table = $('#tbl_questions').DataTable();
var p = table.rows({ page: 'current' }).nodes();
```

will return all the rows in the current page only..

Comment: i have 200 pages of contacts in my datatable. how i select all contacts with a option ?

Comment: @saleemnfs Instead of using the parameter value current you can use "all"

Comment: Very nice solution! :)

Answer (score 2):

Use **dataTables.checkboxes.min.js** , Use option `"selectAllPages" : false` . It should be work and it's easy

Answer (score 0):

`fnGetNodes()` returns all the generated rows. Use this to get the current displayed table rows:

```
$('#Tab_ApplicantList> tbody > tr').each(function() 
{
    $(this).find("input.grey").iCheck('check');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that.. But honestly I believe there is some dedicated Datatable inbuilt functions for that purpose...