# jquery iterate through paginated table

Tags: jquery

i have a checkbox input in each `tr` in the table . 
 i was able to get all rows of the datatable using [rows().every()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().every())

```
<table id="CanalsTable" class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Canal Name</td>
        <td>Canal Description</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var Canal in Canals) {
        <tr id="@Canal.Id">
            <td>
                <span class="m-list-settings__item-control">
                    <span class="m-switch m-switch--outline m-switch--icon-check m-switch--brand">
                        <label>
                            <input onchange="CanalChanged('@Canal.Id')" type="checkbox" name="enabled-@Canal.Id" id="enabled-@Canal.Id">
                            <span></span>
                        </label>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

at the document load we change some checkboxes to their states (enabled/disabled)

```
$("enabled-" + Id).prop('checked', true).change();
```

then when iterating

```
table.rows().every(function () {
    var data = this.data();
    var enabled = $("#enabled-" + data.DT_RowId).is(':checked');
    console.log(enabled);
});
```

it only output true if you're currently in the same page as the checked checkboxes otherwise it always output false.

is there any way to get the exact values ?

Comment: What is the chance that you can create an actual working example. It's kind of hard to understand the whole picture (For example, where the data (from `this.data()`) coming from. What is the logic to set the checkboxes to checked (and then trigger `change`?)

Comment: @MoshFeu the data is the current object var data = `this.data();` when interating using every

Comment: When you say `in the same page as the checked checkboxes`, what does actually mean?

Comment: @imvain2 that you are currently viewing the page where the checked checkboxes are

Comment: This might answer your question. The problem is you need to get the CURRENT page rows, not ALL of them. https://stackoverflow.com/a/27055191/3684265